# Hadoop environment setup

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to install hadoop in my ubuntu 15.4 machine,and getting Hadoop command not found everytime.
I have configured everything in hadoop/conf and my .bashrc entries are :

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

and when i tried `echo $PATH`, the result is:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

It is pointing `usr/local`. I have nothing to do with this location.

And `echo $HADOOP_HOME` results nothing.
How to solve this ?

Comment: in order to your .bashrc changes take effect just exit and login to your user session again

Answer (score 1):

Either restart your computer or Source the bashrc

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then try again